# Get document from Firestore with service account

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-authentication, service-accounts

Im trying to make an Oauth2 request with a service account to Firestore but it keeps saying `Missing or insufficient permissions.`, I am using the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore`. I can use the service account to write to the Google Sheets API. Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, under [IAM in GCP console](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam) add your Service Account and give it the permissions according to: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/access/iam. Then use the oauth scope: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore`. I guess google decided it would be a good idea call Firebase, Datastore for the permissions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).